# Android Button: always error when add ClickEvent

Tags: android, button, nullpointerexception, mouseclick-event

I create a button from layout and it works fine(display on screen when I test). When I add the click event for this `Button`, I always receive a `NullPointerException` (you can see in the below code):

```
   Button b1;
   int REQUEST_CODE =1;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.web_button);        
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { //ERROR THIS LINE

            public void onClick(View arg0){}
        }); 
        setContentView(R.layout.intent);
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching for the `Button` before you set the content view. You'll have to do this:

```
 @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.intent);
            b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.web_button);        
            b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { //ERROR THIS LINE
                public void onClick(View arg0){
                }
            }); 


        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should `setContentView` first - before using `findViewById` - otherwise it doesn't know where to search for your buttons.

Use this order:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.intent);

        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.web_button);        
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { //ERROR THIS LINE
            public void onClick(View arg0){
            }
        }); 
    }
```